# Set selected value jQuery dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, select, set, selected

I am trying to set the selected value in a dropdownlist using jquery, I have this:

```
 $('.option_vehiculo', '#form_login').each(function() 
{
    if (this.id == tipo_vehiculo_def)
    {
         this.value = "option";
    };  
});
```

`.option_vehiculo` is a class that I give to all my dropdownlists so I can find them quickly.

I iterate through all my form dropdownlists until I find the one I want to modify. Finding the select I want to change works fine, but I can't set the selected value, I tried this as I am doing with my input fields:

```
this.value = "option";
```

where option is an option inside my dropdownlist, but all I get from this is my dropdownlist with no selected value, it just appears with no text inside and with the possibility to select one of my available options.

How do I set the selected value of a jQuery dropdownlist?

---

**Attempts:** I tried with this, but I am getting no results and I am not sure if I can use it with 'this' variable as the object I want to modify:

```
this.val("option");
```

tried this:

```
$('#tipo_vehiculo_1000').val("4");
var test = $('#tipo_vehiculo_1000').val();
```

selecting my dropdownlist by id and trying to change my selected option and outputting it later and it keeps giving me the default value "0".

Comment: Show your markup. I sense that you are doing a big mistake.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of iterating through  all of them you can simply use your id value in a jQuery selector

```
 $('#'+tipo_vehiculo_def).val('option')
```

This assumes that you have an option tag in the select with value="option". Also assumes that since ID's must be unique in a page you haven't duplicated any ID's